# What kind of perspective is this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I want to make something similar to this, but I can't figure out what the perspective is called. It seems like it is an aerial perspective maybe, but it's not quite looking straight down. Can someone help me figure this out?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking this isn't a *perspective projection* but a mix of different *parallel projections*. (In *perspective projections* objects that are far away appear smaller than objects that are nearby, and that doesn't happen in this drawing.)

The landscape and the houses are drawn in the kind of *orthographic projection* which is called *axonometric projection* and specifically it's called **trimetric projection** because the three axes of space appear unequally foreshortened. (*Isometric projection*, as mentioned in another answer, is another kind of *axonometric projection* where the three axes of space appear equally foreshortened. There is also a kind called *dimetric projection* where two of the three axes of space appear equally foreshortened.)

The trees and animals are simply drawn in **side/front view**.

The drawing is cut off in the top, which gives the impression of a horizon. Axonometric drawings don't have a horizon, but just continues endlessly.

There is a good article with many illustrations on Wikipedia about [3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection).

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistent? `:)`

I think it's trying to be **isometric** overall. It's kind of free and loose in style, so it doesn't strictly adhere to isometric. But that's as close as I'd put any name.